# Динамический обработчик событий для контрола в VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-webforms

Динамически создаю на странице контролы (checkbox, textbox) и хочу добавить к ним обработчики событий. Задаю их через конструкцию

```
 AddHandler chkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf Me.CheckedChanged
```

Обработчик объявлен как

```
Private Sub CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Но когда кликаю на чекбокс, то в обработчик не попадаю.
Инициализировал контролы и в `page_load`, и в `page_preinit`, и в `page_init` - не помогает. Чую что-то тут не так :)

версия .net 2.0, среда VS2005 (перейти на более новую версию не предлагать :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чекбоксы по умолчанию не вызывают отправку данных на сервер при клике на них, поэтому событие не отрабатывает. Варианты решения:

- Вы можете отправить форму на сервер при помощи другого контрола на форме, который выполняет отправку по умолчанию, например, это происходит при нажатии на кнопку. При этом, если были клики на чекбоксе до отправки данных на сервер, событие отработает.
- Установить свойство `AutoPostBack` в `True` у создаваемого чекбокса (тогда чекбокс сам будет инициировать постбэк при клике на нем).

Пример:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox
    chkbox = New CheckBox
    chkbox.Text = "test"
    chkbox.ID = "id"
    chkbox.AutoPostBack = True
    AddHandler chkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf Me.CheckedChanged
    Form.Controls.Add(chkbox)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Write("Hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: вот пробовал так - не получалось, а сейчас что-то в голове на место встало и получилось! осталось распрямить руки и будет щастье :) спасибо! надо было раньше задать вопрос - не пропало бы 3 дня ))